# firebase deployment after redirect below page

Tags: reactjs, firebase

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3NGG.png)
I want to host my app on firebase.

I followed these steps.

npm run build and it created build folder
firebase init, select hosting,

1. What do you want to use as your public directory? build
2. Configure as a single-page app (rewrite all URLs to /index.html)?
   Yes
3. File build/index.html already exists. Overwrite? No
4. and then finally firebase deploy

after some time I see files uploaded successfully and in the firebase hosting dashboard it shows files uploaded something like 727. but the app looks something like a welcome message "Welcome Firebase Hosting Setup Complete. You're seeing this because you've successfully set up Firebase Hosting. Now it's time to go build something extraordinary!"
however, if I create a react app using create-react-app, and follow the same steps, it's working fine at the same URL and host. it displays the app at once without a problem.

my firebase.json

Answer (score 1):

Firsty once you deploy it try viewing it on incognito mode as sometimes due to the cache it renders the same page

now still if you have errors follow this steps given in the link I followed this and got mine online
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IDHfvpsYShs&t=337s

Comment: I was seeing blank page for so long. Opening in incognito worked. Thank you so much!!!